# Ubuntu laptop keyboard half-functional

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, gnome

Right half of the built-in keyboard in my Asus laptop stopped working under Gnome. For instance, keys <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> <kbd>;</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd>  <kbd>.</kbd> <kbd>/</kbd> don't work.

They do work fine when pressed on external USB keyboard or on in-built one while on the login screen or in laptop's BIOS.

So I presume that's something to do with Gnome itself?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

also check numlock with the possibility for it being numpad, 
in a recent update of ubuntu, the numpad mouse control get turned on,

it can be disable by:
System>prefs>keyboard>mouse keys

i found this out when my numpad stopped working

Answer (score 3):

Those keys...aren't they multifunction, like supposed to take over for the number pad if a function key is pressed or it's put into a certain mode to accept keypad input?

Comment: yes you right! they are! they just behavie like 'Fn' is pressed all the time. When I press Fn and hold it, they do behave like normal keys.

Answer (score 0):

Boot another distro's live CD and see if the problem persists (for example, Knoppix since it uses KDE). If it does, it may be a H/W issue.

Comment: Please see above - it's not hardware issue, keys working fine in bios and ubuntu login screen.